# Java Matcher.find $ matches newline in single line mode

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying the following Pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+)$");
```

Strangely, IMHO:

```
p.matcher("123\n").find() == true;
p.matcher("123\n").lookingAt() == true;  // also weird
p.matcher("123\n\n").find() == false;    // ok
p.matcher("123\na").find() == false;     // also ok
p.matcher("123\n").matches() == false;   // ok to me
```

Quoting the documentation for the "multiline flag" from the Javadocs:

> Enables multiline mode.
> In multiline mode the expressions ^ and $ match just after or just before, respectively, a line terminator or the end of the input sequence. By default these expressions only match at the beginning and the end of the entire input sequence.

Well, to me '\n' (i.e the new line character) is not the end of the input sequence, so '$' should only match it in multiline mode.

Am I missing something or is this a bug in Java. Also, if you try the same pattern and test strings in Javascript you will see that Javascript behaves properly:

```
/^(\d+)$/.test("123\n") == false
/^(\d+)$/.exec("123\n") == null
```

(I'm using Java 8, on RHEL 7.2, by the way)

Thanks!

(EDIT: I should have done this a long time ago: I've filed a bug request with Oracle for this. We will see what happens.)

Answer (score -1):

EOL depends of operation system.

Try to change your test pattern to "123"+System.lineSeparator()

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still same issue using System.lineSeparator().